# How do i do an LDAP query windows form C#, and display the results in multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, ldap, location

I have a Windows Forms application in C# with the .NET Framework 4.0 with two requirements

1. Run a LDAP query.
2. Display the results in multiple textboxes

For example: textbox1= EID (employee id) this is the only "key" that is binded to a user, this eid textbox will start the query and then the results will be pulled from our LDAP and   email, phone number, exchange server, computer name, site location, and alot more..

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For LDAP use LdapConnection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.aspx

And dont forget to dispose of the object!

For the GUI thing, well just put some effort!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on .NET 4.0, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
       txtUserName.Text = user.GivenName + ' ' + user.Surname;
       // etc.

    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!